# What should I make my computer do while I'm away from keyboard?

Tags: linux, backup, automation, gnu, maintenance

During the day, usually I'm away from my computer for 3-5 hours. I also sleep 6+ hours every night.

I run **Arch Linux x64** on my computer.

Besides the usual things that do not require user intervention (torrenting, backing up data, upgrading the system, etc...), is there anything useful that I can let my computer do while I'm away?

Considering I almost never turn the computer off, it seems like a waste it's sitting there doing nothing. I'm looking for any kind of suggestion, not only machine maintenance.

Comment: Why not just let it **idle** and save on your energy bill?

Comment: @eldering, if you're looking to save energy, why would you even leave the machine on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is. There are quite a few projects that use idle computers for scientific research, the most famous (at least the ones *I* know) are:

- [SETI@home](http://setiathome.berkeley.edu/):

  > SETI@home is a scientific experiment that uses Internet-connected computers in the Search for Extraterrestrial Intelligence (SETI). You can participate by running a free program that downloads and analyzes radio telescope data.
- [Folding@home](http://folding.stanford.edu/):

  > Help Stanford University scientists studying Alzheimer's, Huntington's, Parkinson's, and many cancers by simply running a piece of software on your computer.
  >
  > The problems we are trying to solve require so many calculations, we ask people to donate their unused computer power to crunch some of the numbers.

---

If you're only interested in administrative tasks, you could lso consider running things like `updatedb` to refresh `locate`'s database.

Comment: I was half way through writing the same thing. :)

Comment: just remember, your computer will be doing work running these, often maxing CPU usage.  More work = more electricity and heat.  More electricity and heat = more $.

Answer (score 7):

Wikipedia has a [list of distributed computing projects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distributed_computing_projects) that you could contribute to.

You could also ["mine" bitcoin](https://www.weusecoins.com/en/mining-guide), although I'm not sure how much money you'd net after paying for electricity.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think this is a beautiful question.

I myself run [Folding@home](http://folding.stanford.edu/) some nights on my machine, although I have a very old PC. If you have a good set of hardware equipments, you might want to try it too. It is basically a distributed computing project, trying to find cures for some kinds of cancers.

I found them one night, when I was thinking about: "Would we be able to build the strongest supercomputer in the world, by uniting all the seemingly small PCs and smartphones, and then let the users use this power on a shared basis. Like when you want to do some processing and need a powerful CPU, well, you can use this huge network of CPUs." Then I googled for "Shared computing", and I was directed to [**this**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distributed_computing_projects) Wikipedia article. In there you can find a huge list of such projects that you could and might possibly want to devote your computing power to.